# Python Как добавить запятую в строке

Tags: python

У меня есть число в строке, к которому нужно добавить запятую через 3 знака (**с конца**).

---

Например

Исходная строка: 
`122236055`

Нужно: 
`122236,055`

---

Исходная строка: 
`123456789`

Нужно: 
`123456,789`

---

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выводишь переменную, то перед выводом дели на 1000.

Например:

```
a = 123456789
a = a/1000
print(a)
```

Вывод программы: 123456,789.

Comment: От настроек локали будет зависеть. В Google Colab точку ставит, а не запятую, например.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать срезы и `f-строку`:

```
n = '122236055'
print(f'{n[:-3]},{n[-3:]}')
# 122236,055
```

Answer (score 0):

Если число, то, как уже выше сказали: `a/1000`, но при приведении к строковому типу наверняка будет точка вместо запятой.
Можно воспользоваться стандартным модулем locale или просто заменить точку.

```py
import locale
a = 123456789

locale.str(a / 1000)
# ИЛИ
str(a / 1000).replace('.', ',')
```

Если это строка, вариантов тоже несколько:

```py
b = '123456789'

# Первый
c = float(b) / 1000

# Второй
c = b[:len(b)-3] + ',' + b[len(b)-3:]
```

В первом я просто конвертирую строку в число с плавающей запятой, во втором перед последними 3-мя символами добавляю запятую.

Comment: А какой смысл тут в явном использовании дефолтной `locale`? Она и так используется при выводе, насколько я понимаю. И `len(b)` в срезах лишнее, питон при использовании отрицательных индексов и сам её вычислит и подставит.